# What is SaltKey in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql, salt

What is the purpose of saltkey in the t-sql. For example in aspdotnetstorefront databse there is a table name customer, we encrypt/decrypt password then there is another field called SaltKey, what is the purpose of it?

Comment: What is the aspdotnetstorefront database? Can you show us a code example?

Comment: @Oded for someone who's never heard of salting, it's a reasonable though incorrect guess.

Comment: @Davy8 - I would say that if it is in a _customer_ table, it is related to the customer data. If it were a system table or a SQL keyword, I would agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 it has to do with encryption and not T-SQL

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague, but I think you are looking for information about a salt, which is a cryptographic concept and not a relational database one. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29):

> The benefit provided by using a salted password is making a lookup
>   table assisted dictionary attack against the stored values
>   impractical, provided the salt is large enough. That is, an attacker
>   would not be able to create a precomputed lookup table (i.e. a rainbow
>   table) of hashed values (password + salt), because it would take too
>   much space. A simple dictionary attack is still very possible,
>   although much slower since it cannot be precomputed.

Answer (score 0):

better look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Answer (score 0):

see here http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.html
this will help you out to find what is salt..